# Android - load values from sqlite database to an arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am new to android . I have an application working with SQLite DB.
I need to push values from  database to an arraylist of type object.
The code i used is given here.

```
 private ArrayList<objectname> objectList  = new ArrayList<objectname>();
 //function used to get values from database
   public ArrayList<objectname> getResults() {

    MyDb db = new MyDb(this); //my database helper file
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllValues(); //function to retrieve all values from a table- written in MyDb.java file
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {         
            String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));

            try
            {
                ob = new objectname();
                ob.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));// setDate function is written in Class file
                objectList.add(ob);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Error " + e.toString());
            }

         } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
       db.close();
       return objectList;
}
```

This is not working correctly. Not shown any errors but i didn't get values in to the arraylist objectList

Please help me..Thanks in advance..

Comment: What parameter does "this" satisfy when creating your DB manager instance? What does the constructor look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
private ArrayList<objectname> objectList  = getResults();

private ArrayList<objectname> getResults() {

    MyDb db = new MyDb(this); //my database helper file
    db.open(); 

    ArrayList<objectname> resultList = new ArrayList<objectname>();


    Cursor c = db.getAllValues(); //function to retrieve all values from a table- written in MyDb.java file
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));

        try
        {
            ob = new objectname();
            ob.setDate(date);// setDate function is written in Class file
            resultList.add(ob);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Error " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    c.close();

    db.close();
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: Its worked, when i removed db.close() from my code and incuded c.close(). But i think db.open() and db.close() is necessary . But now the problem is that ,some errors and warning statements are shown in logcat..WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(10839): Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(10839): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here .close() was never explicitly called on database .And some more database errors also showing

Comment: add db.close(); after c.close();

Comment: thanks runor49 for your help .Your help is really appreciable and +1 for your help . Can you please help me out in this problem at given link ..                                                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848915/multiple-database-in-single-app-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with retrieving values from the db using cursors and displaying on screen.. The below solution works for me..

```
            Cursor cur = db.getAllValues();
            int index = c.getColumnIndex("date");
    cur.moveToFirst();

    while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
        System.out.println(cur.getString(index)); // For debug purposes
        String date = cur.getString(index);
        try {
            ob = new objectname();
            ob.setDate(date);
            resultList.add(ob);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Error " + e.toString());
        }
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your query is drawing a blank and `moveToFirst` is returning false.

What about logging the value of `c.getCount()` before your `if` statement?

Comment: Then your code should work. Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: Thanks  Matthew Willis.My actual code looks similar to the one i posted here.

Comment: Probably the difference between the actual code and the code you posted is where the error is.