# Retrieve TextView attributes from SQLite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 10 TextViews, their text and visibility is stored in an SQLite db. When an activity loads, I need to grab these values and apply them to the TextViews.

My db is currently structured as: `_id, textviewID, text, visibility`. What would be the best way to access these values and apply them to the correct TextView?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.hdelossantos.com/2010/01/07/using-a-sqlite-database-in-android/), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482402/android-load-values-from-sqlite-database-to-an-arraylist), and of course the [Android Developer's topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) on how to retirieve values from an sqlite db.

For these kind of configurations `SharedPreferences` are way more handy solution. If your design is not strict to use the local database for storing application preferences, you should consider it as an option.

Comment: I had considered SharedPreferences. However, in the end I will have 20 views with 5 attributes each to store. And there will be multiples of this. So I could end up with 50 sets of 100 attributes. Is that too much for ShardPreferences?

Comment: I see, at that amount (not that there was a limit for `SharedPreferences` other than the storage size) it's probably best to use database, to keep the settings clear. The `SharedPreferences` object is stored in one xml, so it would get huge and hard to process.