# Multiple databases in a single app in Android

Tags: android, database

I am working on app in which I would like to use two sqlite database in single app. Is this possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It totally is. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Why don't you add tables instead of multiple DB?

Comment: Vladimir , i am new to android means i am beginer so can u please help me with any sample code or example in which we can use two database for single app .Actually i know how to use single database but not how to use two database in single app n moreover i want to add attributes in database at runtime also..

Comment: Vinay , Thanks for your concern ..                                         but actually it is requirement of my application to have two db and attributes of tables inside db should be genreated at runtime.

Comment: Any pro and con of using multiple databases.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to have multiple databases in a single app. If you can do without multiple databases, you can have just a single database with multiple tables. You can use adb to view the databases and execute queries against them

Comment: thanks for replying rihan..                                                  Actully table attributes have to be genreated at runtime so there can be two tables with same name .So i need to create two db .

Comment: I don't think it is a better idea to have multiple databases you should go with creating multiple tables in a single database.for your problem tables of same name you can check and compare the names at run time they are sane you can give it a different name or append something in table name for example if your table name is mTable and user created mTable again you can give it a different name like mTable1.

Comment: sunny i cant apply your idea because table values will come from json

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple SQLite databases.

A SQLite database is just a file.

You set the name the file (database) with the `databaseName`:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, /*->*/ databaseName /*<-*/, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

To create multiple databases, use different database names:

```
final var database1 = new DatabaseHelper(context, "database1");
final var database2 = new DatabaseHelper(context, "database2");
```

---

*Just fyi:*

You can see your databases when you install your app on a device, connect the device via Android Studio (adb), open `Device File Explorer`, browser to `data/data/com.your.app/databases`

In the example above you'll find at least two files:

- `database1`
- `database2`

And usually also

- `database1-journal`
- `database2-journal`

Any maybe another file for each database which contains unsaved (unmerged) changes to that database.

Comment: As this question pops up first on Google, I added an answer with example code.