# Two database in one app

Tags: android, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple database in single app in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848915/multiple-database-in-single-app-in-android)

I have one app with it's database file. Now i want to build another database file in this app to store another kind of data. Is it posible?

Comment: Perhaps this may be answer to your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848915/multiple-database-in-single-app-in-android

Comment: you need another table, not second database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is possible to have multiple database in single app, *still I will suggest to have multiple tables in single database instead of multiple database.*

Here is a solution to create multiple database.

[How to add multiple database in single app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4499816/519718)