# Saving ArrayList<Map<String, String>> to a SQLite Database?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have a `Fragment` called `HistoryFragment` which contains a `ListView`. The items of the `ListView` are added by another class called `DataModel`.  What I'm trying to do is to save the list whenever an item is added to the list.   (At the moment, the views in my list are only `TextView`s, but later I hope to add images to them, and have multiple lines etc. so these will need to be saved as well). My list is: `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` and it is called `mPlanetList`.

I think saving to a `SQLiteDataBase` is the solution, but is seems very complicated even after reading multiple answers/tutorials.

Some sites that I've looked at:

```
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5482402/2442638
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3142285/2442638
```

There are lots of questions in this "question" but my main question comes in two parts:

a)   Is a `DataBase` the right solution?

--> If 'yes' --> b) What is a simple way to make one?  I would prefer not to use JSON/GSON

--> If 'no' -->  c) What should I use instead?  `SharedPreferences`?

Assuming a `DataBase` is the correct solution, I think I need to serialize my arraylist or possibly use a StringSet - I have no idea how to do that as I have an arraylist like this: `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>`  as opposed to an arraylist without the map object.

Also, I tried to access my DataBase from my `DataModel` class (as this is where I add my items to the list) but I can't get it to work.

I have added my current code - the work for the DataBase is not complete, but I am stuck with what I should do next.

This is my `HistoryFragment` class:

```
// Remove imports

public class HistoryFragment extends FragmentBase implements OnItemAddedHandler {
// FragmentBase is just another class which extends Fragment and the moment.

    ListView lv;
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, container, false);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);


        List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = DataModel.getInstance()
                .getPlanetList();
        simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), planetsList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "planet" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;

        // Display a dialog
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemAdded(Object data) {
        simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.scrollTo(0, 0); // Scrolls to top of list
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        DataModel.getInstance().setOnItemAddedHandler(this);
    }

}
```

This is my `DataModel`:

```
public class DataModel {

    private List<Map<String, String>> mPlanetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    private static DataModel instance;
    private static OnItemAddedHandler mOnItemAddHandler;

    private DataModel() {
        initList();
    }

    public static DataModel getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new DataModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private void initList() { 
// Here is where I want to load the saved listitems.
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getPlanetList() {
        return mPlanetsList;
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {

        HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
        planet.put(key, name);
        return planet;
    }

    public void setOnItemAddedHandler(OnItemAddedHandler handler) {
        mOnItemAddHandler = handler;
    }

    public void addItem(Object data) { // Save stuff here?
        Bundle data1 = new Bundle();
        String string = ((Bundle) data).getString("keyTitle");
        mPlanetsList.add(0, createPlanet("planet", string)); 

 // This is where I want to save my items to the DataBase
    HistoryDataBase.getInstance();  //Adding .getWritableDatabase()  gives me a nullpointerexception.

// I don't understand what else I need to do here to add my mPlanetList to the DataBase

        if (null != mOnItemAddHandler) {
            mOnItemAddHandler.onItemAdded(data1);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is my DataBase:

```
public class HistoryDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static HistoryDataBase instance;

public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " KEY, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";

static Context c;

HistoryDataBase(Context context) {
    super(c, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static HistoryDataBase getInstance() {
    if (null == instance) {

        instance = new HistoryDataBase(c);
    }
    return instance;
}
}
```

Very basically:  I want to save my listitems permanently, and be able to retreive, edit and delete them.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.  If any clarification is needed, please say.

Comment: You Don't need to use dataModel for it. just create SQLLITEHelper class for PlanetData and add Methods for inserting Data in table in it and call it from history fragment class. and add another get data method in SQLHelper for getting all data, and call that method when you need any data

Comment: @ArmaanStranger I use DataModel to add the items because the strings come from a different fragment

Comment: ohk...bt if you are using SQLLite than you can add data directly to SQL table so you will get data directly in another fragment.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger Thats a good idea!  So I basically need to to change DataModel to a public DataBase which I add data to from my other fragment and retrieve the data from HisoryFragment.

Comment: Yes right. your database is global so changes in data from one fragment will reflect in another. so your life would be easier.

Answer (score 6):

The `SQLiteDataBase` is the correct solution.

You can save the data of every item into database. There will be a `HashMap<String, Object>` instead of `HashMap<String, String>` in each item data, in case of you want to put integer or other simple type data into the hashmap.

Then, you can serialize the `HashMap` into `json` when you are going to save it into database:

```
    // you can put multiple data into this hashmap
    HashMap<String, Object> dataHashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("data", new JSONObject(dataHashMap).toString());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID, values);
```

You can do `unserialize` after fetch the serialized data from database:

```
    int rawDataIndex = 6;
    String rawData = cursor.getString(rawDataIndex);
    HashMap<String, Object> dataHashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(rawData);
        JSONArray names = json.names();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
            String key = names.getString(i);
            dataHashMap.put(key, json.opt(key));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can we store custom object instead of Object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the structure of JSONArray, where each one of the elements is a JSONObject.

JSON has default constructor to convert the data into string and parse from string.

So, what you need is a TEXT field in the database.